# htaccess 301 redirect issues

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**Problem:** I just did a major update to my companies website and trying to get some redirects to work. Right now if I have

```
Redirect 301 folder1/oldFile1.html http://www.mysite.com/newFolder1/newFolder2/newFile.html
```

and when you got to the new set up, I get this instead with a 404

`http://www.mysite.com/newFolder1/newFolder2/newFile.htmloldFile.html`

any ideas what is causing this?

*Note: this only appears to happen to files that are moving from a 1 folder structure to a 2 folder structure.*

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mysite.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [r=301,nc] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_rewrite` rules with `mod_alias` rules.

Use this instead:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L] 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/.*index\.html?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^folder1/oldFile1\.html$ /newFolder1/newFolder2/newFile.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOOOOOO MUCH! You are my hero for the day!